# How do I fix error in updating table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to create a column with date using 2 other columns(month and year) by writing this query

```
update [dbo].[National_Data]
set [date] = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONCAT([year] ,'-',[month],'-','01'))
              from [dbo].[National_Data])
```

It returns the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

I guess the problem is that the query I wrote does not read row by row,
how can I fix this?

Comment: The error is, in truth, telling you the problem. If you run that subquery you're quickly see it returns many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery.  Just use the expression:

```
update [dbo].[National_Data]
    set [date] = CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT([year] , '-', [month], '-01'));
```

You can write this more succintly using `datefromparts()`:

```
update [dbo].[National_Data]
    set [date] = datefromparts([year], [month], 1);
```

Or to be sure that the `date` value is consistent with the other two, I would recommend using a computed column instead of `update`.  The syntax would look like:

```
alter table National_Data add date as
    (datefromparts([year], [month], 1));
```

Comment: First one is still expression or invalid statement.

Comment: Since the query been modified, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need subquery for this update query

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[National_Data]
SET [date] = CAST(CONCAT([year] , '-', [month], '-01') AS DATETIME);
```